# How to fetch token from header and validate it with userdetails in postman rest client in php

Tags: php, mysql, rest

When user logged in which generate **base64encode token** and copy that token to the header of **postman** rest client for next service call how to fetch the same token from header and **validate** the user details **who is logged in** and get the details of the user who is logged in

Comment: `$headers=apache_request_headers();` This is used for fetch data from header

Comment: i got it this one but how to fetch the token from header>

Comment: just print out the $header
`echo "<pre>";print_r($headers);die;`

Comment: i am printed already but my question is how to fetch x-access-token from header and validate it with username who is logged in